# Compare values of two multidimentional array and insert if not exits

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have two array `$array1` and `$array2` which I get dynamically and look like

```
$array1 = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 10
                [activity] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 1
                                [cnt] => 2
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 2
                                [cnt] => 1
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 11
                [activity] => Array
                    (
                    )
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 12
                [percentage] => 0
                [activity] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 2
                                [cnt] => 5
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 3
                                [cnt] => 2
                            )
                    )
            )
    );


$array2 = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Phone Calls
                [readable] => 1
                [status] => active
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Meeting With Customer
                [readable] => 1
                [status] => active
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [name] => Others Works
                [readable] => 1
                [status] => active
            )
    );
```

which i need to compare.

if `$array2['id']` is not in `$array1["activity"]`(i.e"activity_id") add array `['activity_id'=>$array2['id'],'cnt'=>0]` to  `$array1['activity']`.

My result must be like

```
$result = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 10
                [activity] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 1
                                [cnt] => 2
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 2
                                [cnt] => 1
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 3
                                [cnt] => 0
                            )
                    )
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 11
                [activity] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 1
                                [cnt] => 0
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 2
                                [cnt] => 0
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 3
                                [cnt] => 0
                            )
                    )
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 12
                [percentage] => 0
                [activity] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 1
                                [cnt] => 0
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 2
                                [cnt] => 5
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 3
                                [cnt] => 2
                            )
                    )
            )
    );
```

What i have tried is

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $arr1) {
    foreach($array2 as $arr2) {
        if(!in_array($arr2['id'], $arr1['activity'])) {
            $array = ['activity_id'=>$arr2['id'], 'cnt'=>0];   
        }
        array_push($arr1['activity'], $array);
        unset($array);
    }
    array_push($finalArray, $result);
}
print_r($finalArray);
```

`in_array()` function is not working as I excepted or I am trying to do it in the wrong way. Can someone helps me with this?

Comment: If I understand you code correctly, what you want to know is if the index exists in the first array (not value). In that case, what you need is : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-key-exists.php. Let met know if I'm right.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.You can see in $result array $result[0][activity] there is added  [2] => Array
                            (
                                [activity_id] => 3
                                [cnt] => 0
                            ).If you see my working array and $result array may be its easy for you to understand.$result array is the output that i need.

Comment: What I meant is: Is your objective to match a key in your `$arr1['activity']` array or a value?

Comment: objective is to see $array2[][id] value is exist in $array1[]['activity'][]['activity_id'].If not exist then add array with activity_id and cnt 0 to that array.

Comment: As you code is currently is, `in_array` try to match `$arr2['id']` with `[0] => Array( [activity_id] => 1 [cnt] => 2)` not `[]['activity_id']`. An id will not match with an array.

Comment: yap i mean to say [] means [0],[1][2]......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,finally i get what i did wrong.May be someone get helped.

everything is ok just change the line

```
if(!in_array($arr2['id'], $arr1['activity'])) {
```

into

```
if(!in_array( $readActivity['id'], array_column($result['activity'],'activity_id'))){
```